# Why does ESXi 5.5 freeze at the "Initializing ACPI" stage?

Tags: esxi

I installed ESXi 5.5 on "unsupported" hardware (probably), it installed fine but when trying to boot after installation the boot froze with the message "Initializing ACPI".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the problem might come from using a UEFI motherboard. The solution is to remove any UEFI boot option from the priority list, so in my case I only have the SATA optical drive and SATA hard drive options. I'd love to know why this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question is quite old, but for future reference this might help if you are able to switch between legacy and UEFI boot mode. ESXi 5.5 uses a GPT partition table by default which requires an UEFI boot mode to boot from. However, as pointed out above, ESXi hangs on first boot after the installation during 'initializing ACPI' when booting from certain UEFI bioses. As a workaround you can force ESXi to use a MBR partition table. During setup (after the blue screen where you can choose ehat Edition of ESXi you want to install) you can press ctrl+o to edit the boot options. Append a space and the option 'formatwithmbr' and press enter (so the complete boot option reads 'runweasel formatwithmbr'). The MBR partition table enables legacy bioses to boot from this disk. This solved my problem with a white box ESXi using an old Intel Q67 mainboard.